# Create column that shows percentage +/- from previous period

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, percentage

I have this dataframe, I want to create a column that shows the % change for the Amount from the Period to Current Period, while grouping by Company_Id, Country, and Period.

```
Company_Id  Country     Period         Amount
MOO17       USA       Previous Period   500
KQR20       UK        Previous Period   1000    
KQR20       UK        Current Period    20000
ABY88       Ireland    Previous Period  1000
ABY88       Ireland    Current Period   250 
SOQ99       Japan      Previous Period  8000
SOQ99       Japan      Current Period   25000
RTU89       China      Current Period   20000
RTU89       China      Previous Period  1000
WER67       Canada     Current Period   5000
WER67       Canada     Previous Period  20000
```

I have tried the following:

```
df['desired']= df['Amount'] / df.groupby(['Company_Id','Country','Period])['Amount'].shift(1)

df= df.sort_values(by=['Company_Id','Country','Period],ascending=[True, True, False],inplace=True)
df['desired'] = df.groupby(['Company_Id','Country','Period])['Amount].pct_change()
```

I keep getting nans or values that don't align with the groupings I need.

Desired Output:

```
Company_Id  Country     Period         Amount     Desired
MOO17       USA       Previous Period   500        na
KQR20       UK        Previous Period   1000       na
KQR20       UK        Current Period    20000      1900%
ABY88       Ireland    Previous Period  1000       na
ABY88       Ireland    Current Period   250       -75%
SOQ99       Japan      Previous Period  8000      na
SOQ99       Japan      Current Period   25000    212.5%
RTU89       China      Current Period   20000    na
RTU89       China      Previous Period  1000     -95%
WER67       Canada     Current Period   5000     na
WER67       Canada     Previous Period  20000   300%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2['desired'] = df2.groupby(['Company_Id','Country'])['Amount'].pct_change()*100
```

If you want to add the percentage symbol, you can do as below. But, it will change the data type of the column to `object` from `float64`

```
df2['desired'] = (df2.groupby(['Company_Id','Country'])['Amount'].pct_change()*100).astype(str) + '%'
```

[image]

Comment: I've already tried this, it doesn't work for some reason, keep getting nans

Comment: This code is different from yours. In groupby, we should not include column „Period“. I am getting proper values with this. Try one.

Comment: i did, i tried all sorts of variations and it's not working

Comment: I am getting the values you have shown in your desired output. Can you check the dtypes of the columns as make sure Amount is `int64`. you can use `df.dtypes` to check

Comment: I have added the pic of my output as well.

Comment: Company_id                object
Country             object
Period                    object
Amount       float64

Comment: it's working now, there was some issue with the data, can you please tell me how I can round to the nearest tenth? i.e add .round(number , 2)

Comment: df2['desired2'] = (df2.groupby(['Company_Id','Country'])['Amount'].pct_change()*100).round(-1)